# Como validar se foi utilizado operador ternário na implementação?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operadores, testes, tdd

Quero validar através do TDD se na implementação foi aplicada operadores ternários.

Como posso aferir esta situação?

```
def par_impar(x):
   return "impar" if x % 2 else "par"
```

Ou esta outra?

```
par_impar = lambda x: "impar" if x % 2 else "par"
```

Objetivo:

Através do TDD - Test Driven Development (Desenvolvimento Dirigido/Orientado por Testes), tem a finalidade de delinear o desenvolvimento de acordo com os requisitos de projeto. E o desenvolvedor utilizará sua experiência para atendê-los. Como este será de treinamento quero forçar que algumas implementações sejam aplicadas.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Ainda não. estou pesquisando...

Answer (score 6):

## TDD não é isso

TDD não é o que você parece acreditar ser. É uma metodologia de desenvolvimento usada para entender melhor o problema e especificar formalmente como o código deve **resultar**.

Acontece mais ou menos como o ocorrido com OOP, as pessoas acham que é um mecanismo, mas é uma técnica para construir um sistema melhor. O objetivo de OOP não é construir objetos, mas sim construir uma modelagem coerente. O objetivo do TDD não é testar algo e sim modelar algo que faça sentido. Como OOP não entregou o que prometeu agora tentariam mais uma técnica, que não entregou o que prometeu e vão buscar outra (DDD? que também não entrega), quem sabe um dia entendam que não existe técnica que faça isto, é construção do conhecimento geral que gera um modelo melhor.

A forma básica de fazer isso é construir um teste que indique corretamente o resultado, ou seja, você especifica o que terá que ser realizado de forma simples e **depois** construirá um código que dê o **resultado**.

No momento que você escreveu o código que vai realizar algo já acabou a chance de aplicar o TDD.

Mais ainda, assim como acontece muito com OOP, as pessoas acham que podem aprender isto com exercícios artificiais. Não pode, esta forma só ensina errado.

Portanto a pergunta parte de uma premissa errada. Ela não tem o requisito, não tem uma descrição clara e detalhada do problema para escrever o teste que seria a implementação do TDD. Então mesmo que o código a ser executado ainda não existisse não teria como escrever o TDD.

Uma das críticas que sempre faço ao TDD é que ele não resolve nada quando a pessoa não sabe especificar bem. Ele é só uma forma de escrever a especificação, não faz a especificação ser boa e correta. E muitas pessoas acreditam que fazendo o TDD sua aplicação estará correta. TDD é só como escolher usar máquina de escrever em vez de caneta para escrever a especificação, isso tem lá alguma vantagem, mas não resolve o real problema, e tem desvantagem também.

Mas tentando inferir qual é o problema pelo código escrito, e repito, isso não é TDD, você teria que escrever códigos que verificam se ele responde sempre corretamente a algumas entradas de dados, mesmo que o correto seja o errado, porque os melhores testes são os que mandam uma entrada que deve produzir um problema e entender como o código se comporta.

## Como deve ser TDD

Nesse caso faz sentido chamar esta função passando como argumento alguns números, por exemplo o 0, alguns positivos pequenos em sequência, incluindo aí pares e ímpares, números primos, números negativos, números muito grandes (em Python não é necessário verificar estouro de capacidade do tipo numérico específico porque ele lida com isto sozinho). Precisaria testar com valores que não são números, como booleano ou *string*, ou objetos em geral, nada destas entradas deveriam ser aceitas.

O teste tem que verificar se o retorno da função é o que espera ou se ela lança algum erro, quando isso é o esperado.

[Python tem um módulo que já ajuda lidar com tudo isto](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/unittest.html). Existem diversas bibliotecas externas ([exemplo](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/)) que ajudam o processo e algumas bem mais sofisticadas, mas o TDD em si pode ser usado com qualquer uma delas, até as mais simples ou mesmo sem nada adicional. E tem [livro sobre](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/).

Um exemplo simples para testar seu código (consulte a documentação para todos os detalhes de utilização e não considere isto como o melhor código para o caso):

```
def teste_par_impar(self):
    self.assertEqual(par_impar(0), "par")
    self.assertEqual(par_impar(1), "impar")
    self.assertEqual(par_impar(2), "par")
    self.assertEqual(par_impar(-1), "impar")
    self.assertEqual(par_impar(-2), "par")
    self.assertEqual(par_impar(9999999999999999999999999999), "impar")
    self.assertEqual(par_impar(-2), "par")
    self.assertRaises(Exception, par_impar("1"))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Tdd.py).

Teria que testar bem mais coisas, por isso sempre digo que as pessoas são ingênuas quando criam testes e o fazem, geralmente, por moda, pra fazer de conta que está fazendo certo porque todo mundo está falando que só assim é certo.

Esse é um caso que mostra como as pessoas tendem a testar o que é fácil demais e não tem muito como dar errado, e em geral elas não testam bem justamente o que pode dar errado (minha experiência que especialmente em TDD as pessoas costumam ignorar essa parte, que é a mais importante, e depois que vai dando problema ela vai adicionando testes mais úteis, que joga o TDD por terra). E é comum as pessoas deixarem os testes mais importantes pra lá porque dá muito trabalho, ela não consegue fazer direito, ou mesmo quando faz não fica bom, cheio de furos e acaba dando só uma falsa sensação de segurança, até que ela desiste (se não aprender fazer direito, tem quem faça, mas é bem raro).

## TDD não verifica implementação

TDD não é uma para validar nada. Faz menos sentido ainda tentar aplicar a técnica olhando para a implementação. Que importa se está usando um operador condicional (que é ternário, mas esta não é função dele, ser ternário é um atributo diferente e secundário do operador), poderia estar usando outra coisa, poderia trocar e o teste não deve ter que ser mudado por causa disto. Nem TDD, nem teste de unidade, nem nada parecido tem objetivo verificar se a implementação está certa, o objetivo destas técnicas é verificar se o contrato estabelecido produz o resultado certo.

O TDD não pode ser usado para verificar se a implementação está de acordo com nada, só se o resultado está. Existe técnica para isto, mas é bem pouco difundida porque geralmente é um erro se preocupar com isto.

## Desenvolver softwares não é codificar

Uma das coisas que sempre falo aqui e muita gente não dá importância é que se a pessoa não consegue fazer uma pergunta adequada aqui é porque ela não está preparada para desenvolver softwares. Ela pode até produzir códigos, mas não desenvolver softwares. Desenvolver softwares envolve muita coisa e vai além de dominar a sintaxe da linguagem e o básico das ferramentas que são usadas no processo. É preciso entender o problema, da maneira correta, é preciso conceituar certo, modelar adequadamente. Precisa ter compreensão de um texto que nem existe ainda, então é preciso produzir um texto condizente, de acordo com o problema apresentado, que mostre a realidade. Muito raro quem consegue fazer isto.

Alguns acham que isto é academicismo ou até elitismo, mas não tem outra forma de fazer correto. Ou a pessoa resolve essa questão ou ela não consegue fazer certo. Só faz TDD certo quem consegue entender e expressar o problema corretamente. Não é o mecanismo que importa, se souber fazer certo o mecanismo pode ser qualquer um, pode ser até algum mais abstrato.

Comment: excelente tua explicação e exemplo!
Entretanto meu objetivo neste caso não é testar o código, e sim aferir se foi implementado com operador ternário.

Para validar os testes estou utilizando unittest. E criei um TDD para treinamento dirigido de estagiários. 

Com este propósito quero validar a implementação de operador ternário, e não o resultado do método.

Comment: Então não entendeu a resposta. TDD ou teste de unidade não servem para isto. Você quer um teste de implementação. Quase ninguém faz isto e quase ninguém fala do assunto. Tem técnica, mas eu nunca usei e especialmente em algo simples duvido que produza algo útil. Isto eu vou ficar devendo, eu respondi porque falava de TDD.

Comment: Excelente a tua resposta!!! Não ficou devendo em nada. TDD - Test Driven Development, Desenvolvimento Dirigido/Orientado por Testes, tem a finalidade de delinear o desenvolvimento de acordo com os requisitos de projeto. E o desenvolvedor utilizará sua experiência para atendê-los. Como este será de treinamento quero forçar que algumas implementações sejam aplicadas.

Comment: @britodfbr Com TDD não dá pra forçar nem verificar uma implementação específica. A ideia do TDD é verificar **o que** o código faz (ex: "*retorna um texto diferente se o número for par ou ímpar*"), mas não **como** isso é feito (tanto faz se é com operador ternário, com if/else, com qualquer outro algoritmo, **não importa**, desde que o resultado seja o esperado). Tanto que se a implementação mudar, o teste deve continuar dando os mesmos resultados. Se quer verificar a implementação, não use TDD...

Comment: @hkotsubo, Ok tudo bem. E você poderia apresentar um teste de implementação para esta situação?

Comment: @britodfbr Sinceramente, nunca precisei fazer isso e não saberia indicar formas de fazê-lo. Eu **acho** que um caminho seria usar analisadores de código - algo similar a um [linter](https://realpython.com/python-code-quality/#linters), por exemplo - e talvez até exista algo mais específico em Python (é a linguagem da moda, *provavelmente* alguém já fez...) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo, ok muito obrigado!